# Nextjs13 on server side rendering How to use axios withCredentials:true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js13

I want to know how to use Axois with credentials true on the server side Nextjs13. I tried this on the server side but `withCredentials:true` not working on the server side but the same code working on the client side

```
 axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/single-blog/${params.slug}`,{withCredentials:true})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because it is client client-specific feature. This option is typically used in web browsers where you are dealing with cross-origin requests and need to include credentials such as cookies, authorization headers, or TLS client certificates.

When `withCredentials` is set to true, `axios` includes any credentials such as cookies or HTTP authentication headers in the request. This is important when you are making requests across different origins (different domains, ports, or protocols make different origins) and need to send or receive cookies or authentication information.

Normally, when making requests to the same same origin, cookies are automatically sent along with the request. The browser handles this behavior by including cookies relevant to the requested domain. However, when you're dealing with cross-origin requests, browsers follow the `Same-Origin Policy`, which restricts the automatic sending of cookies or authentication information.

In server-to-server communication, you typically handle authentication, credentials, or tokens through headers. For example:

```
 axios.get("yourUrl", {
    headers: {
        Cookie: request.headers.cookie
    }
});
```

next.js has [headers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers)

> The headers function allows you to read the HTTP incoming request
> headers from a Server Component.
>
> This API extends the Web Headers API. It is read-only, meaning you
> cannot set / delete the outgoing request headers.

from the same link, you can see how to extract the headers:

import { headers } from 'next/headers'

```
export default function Page() {
  const headersList = headers()
  const referer = headersList.get('referer')
 
  return <div>Referer: {referer}</div>
}
```

Comment: `req.headers.cookie` can u give me full code here I am getting error req is undefined nextjs13

Comment: req just refers to request. in middleware or api function you might be using request